# update db table in php on clicking Ok/Cancel buttons in the js alert box

Tags: javascript, php, alert

I have a php code (all the code is in the same file **mno.php**) in which only one user is allowed to login at one time. When another user login at the same time, an **alert message is displayed**.

When **1st user login**, it goes inside the `else` block **(at Line B)** .

When **2nd user login** **at the same time**,
it goes inside the if block `if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0)` and the alert message will display **(at Line A)** ***user User A is currently login.
Do you want to take over ?*** (with Ok and Cancel buttons).

[image]

**mno.php**

```
/* php function for alert message */
function phpAlert($msg)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">confirm("' . $msg . '")</script>';
}


if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
        if ($row['open'] == "true") {
            if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])) {
                 $message = "user " . $row['user_name'] . " is logged in. Do you want to take over ?";   
                 phpAlert($message); //Line A
            }
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;  // Line B
}
```

On clicking **Ok/Cancel buttons from the alert box**, I want the following query to run:

**Ok button:**
[image]

```
$stmt1=$connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET write_access='0' WHERE write_access='1'"); // revoke write access of all users
$stmt1->execute();
```

**Cancel button:**

[image]

```
session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
!isset($_SESSION['admin']);
header('location: /abc/mno.php');
```

This is what I have tried but I think more need to be done as the if and else blocks below are not called on clicking **Ok** and **Cancel** buttons

```
if ( $_GET[confirm] == "yes" ) {
    $stmt1=$connect->prepare("UPDATE trace_users SET write_access='0' WHERE write_access='1'"); // revoke write access of all users
    $stmt1->execute();
} else if ( $_GET[confirm] == "no" ) {
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
    !isset($_SESSION['admin']);
    header('location: /abc/mno.php');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create two separate php files that includes what you put in your if and else blocks accordingly, then use ajax to call these files. So basically you start with your js script and updat it to call a function not to call confirm directly:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">myConfirmFunction("' . $msg . '")</script>';
```

And implement `myConfirmFunction` in a `<script>` bloc like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myConfirmFunction(message) {
        if(confirm(message)) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "update_trace_users.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: {},
                success: function(result) {
                      // Do something with result
                }
            });
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "session_destroy.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: {}, // you can pass data to your php script
                success: function(result) {
                      // Do something with result
                }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Let's say if I create two files `update_trace_users.php` and `session_destroy.php`. I would  be writing 2 small piece of code in those 2 files. Do you think it's a good idea to create separate two files just to place two small pieces of code ?

Comment: Yes, because after all you cannot mix server side code with client side code.

Comment: If you want you can use only one file and pass some data with the ajax call for the server side code to know what code it should run.

Comment: I am getting error at this line  `});` just after `success: // your success callback` inside if block. It says unexpected token `'}'`.

Comment: I think there is one bracket missing here `if(confirm(message)`.

Comment: are you around ?

Comment: I updated my code example, you should implement a function for success if you want to show a message of success for the user...

Comment: Thanks for the update. It looks really good. The other issue which I am having right now is when the page load, I am getting the error `myConfirmFunction` is not defined although it is 
inside the phpAlert and it should only be called (I believe) when 2nd user tries to login at the same time when 1st user is already logged in.

Comment: This line https://3v4l.org/AtL8P is present at the top of my code.

Comment: It's ok if you put `phpAlert` declaration on top but unfortunately in your case you should put `jquery` + `myConfirmFunction` declaration before caling the `phpAlert` function, for example see https://3v4l.org/kJ55g

Comment: can you accept the answer please if it solves your problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the following conditional lines to work (*and mind the quotes around the key!*):

```
if ( $_GET['confirm'] == "yes" ) {

else if ( $_GET['confirm'] == "no" ) {
```

...there will have to be a query string with `?confirm=yes` or `=no` when your `mno.php` page is called. Now, in your prompt, you simply do the following:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">confirm("' . $msg . '")</script>';
```

However, clicking on a Javascript `confirm` prompt will not accomplish anything on its own. Nothing sent, nothing loaded, and nothing happening. You'll need something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let x = confirm("Take over?");
    window.location.href = '/abc/mno.php?confirm=' + (x === true ? 'yes' : 'no');
</script>
```

In other words, get the (true/false) result of the confirm prompt, and then take action accordingly. Here, the action being: *Reload of your script with the appropriate query string added*.

It seems that this is the simple piece of the puzzle you're missing here. If there are further problems once you plug this in, please update the OP with necessary details, or ask a new question.